# What is the most proper way to declare global variable to use for many modules in Fortran?

Tags: module, fortran, global-variables

The question is: If I want to use global variables in many modules. How should I do?

In my opinion, I think, maybe we could make another module and declare the global variables and then include it to any files that require it or something like that. I think this is a very simple way but the problem is I'm not familiar with Fortran. I don't know how to do it and how normally people do it.

Please give me some easy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a module, perhaps called `global`

```
module global
  implicit none
  real :: my_global_x
  integer :: my_global_i
end module
```

and then you can use it wherever it is needed, in modules

```
module a
  use global ...
end module
```

in subroutines

```
...
subroutine s
  use global
  ...
end subroutine
...
```

or in the main program

```
program main
  use global
  implicit none

  ...
end program
```

You can also use just a limited number of variables from the module to avoid name-space pollution

```
use global, only: my_global_x
```